# Vercel Analytics & Next-intl

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, next-intl

I can't setup vercel Analytics on my project and I think it's because of the middleware from next-intl, despite my config where I have _vercel in it, the problem still persists, do you have a solution?

middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { nextIntlMiddleware } from "./middleware/next-intl-middleware";
import { authMiddleware } from "./middleware/authMiddleware";
import { locales } from "./navigation";

export const middleware = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  const excludePattern = "^(/(" + locales.join("|") + "))?/admin/?.*?$";
  const publicPathnameRegex = RegExp(excludePattern, "i");
  const isPublicPage = !publicPathnameRegex.test(req.nextUrl.pathname);

  const nextIntlMiddlewareResponse = nextIntlMiddleware(req);

  if (isPublicPage) {
    return nextIntlMiddlewareResponse;
  } else {
    return authMiddleware(req);
  }
};

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|logo.png|sw.js|_vercel).*)",
  ],
};
```

[image]

Comment: The consol says that you need to enable analytics from the Vercel dashboard